# Getting status 0 and statusMessage "n/a" in IE7 after ajaxForm.submit()

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-7, ajaxform

I'm uploading a file using the Hayageek upload plugin, which uses the ajaxForm plugin. My problems start when I want to handle upload errors from IE7. It works fine in Firefox, Chrome and IE10, but in IE7 I always get status 0 in the response's xhr object, no matter if the server returns an error or not.

This is my controller's code:

```
Response.StatusCode = 400; //No matter which code I return, I always get 0
return Json(new {ErrorID = 400, Level = 1, Message = "Error message"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

And this is what I'm getting in the xhr object using IE7:

```
{aborted: 0, responseText: "<DIV class=...", responseXML: Object {...}, status: 0, statusText: "n/a"}
```

Notice that in `responseText` I get the entire view, instead of "Error message". This only happens when I specify the Response.StatusCode. If I comment the line `Response.StatusCode = 400;` I get the correct message in `responseText`, but I still get `status : 0`.

I've tried with `dataType: 'json'`, but then I get `status : parseerror`, probably because it's trying to parse the responseText, which is the entire view in HTML instead of the error message that I'm sending back from the controller.

Is there a way to receive a proper status code and a message as a response in IE7 or should I give up?

Comment: I know its not of my concern, but is there any specific reason you are developing for IE7? I am asking since Microsoft stopped support for IE7, so is it expected for applications to be IE7 complaint?

Comment: Have no choice, some of my customers still use it and don't want to change. In any case, I didn't know that Microsoft had stopped support for IE7. Could you show me an official link to send it to my client? I cannot find anyone.

Comment: I just hope [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support) link gets you out of this frustrating problems(and more to come in your way :P). But I doubt whether this can convince your customers. All the best :) @DanielMarin

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try, for the best of human kind.